# Please help with custom trigger

Tags: apex, trigger

I'm trying to build a trigger. When a Property__Rate__c is updated, I would like to Query the next Property_rate__c in line by date(Date__c). This Property_rate__c will not contain the same AccountId, but will contain the same PropertyId.

From there I would like to update the original Property_rate__c.Account__r with the AccountId of the Next Property_Rate__c. This account Id should be stored in a field called Account__c.Next_Arrival__c.

I am not getting any errors with this code, but the AccountId of the next arrival is not populating in the Next_Arrival__c field.

```
trigger setNextArrivalHK on Property_Rate__c (after update) 
{
    List<Property_Rate__c> updatedRateList = new List<Property_Rate__c>();
    Set<String> thisRateId = new Set<String>();

    for (Property_Rate__c rate : Trigger.new)
    {
        thisRateId.add(rate.Account__c);      
        String rateProperty = rate.Property__c;
        Date rateDate = rate.Date__c;     

        List<Property_Rate__c> findNextArrival = [SELECT Id, Account__c, Account__r.Next_Arrival__c, Date__c, Status__c, Property__c FROM Property_Rate__c 
        WHERE date__c >= :rateDate AND Property__c = :rateProperty AND Status__c = 'Booked' AND Account__r.Id NOT IN :thisRateId ORDER BY Date__c DESC];

        for (Property_Rate__c currentRate : findNextArrival)
        {
            currentRate.Account__r.Next_Arrival__c = findNextArrival[0].Account__r.Id;
            updatedRateList.add(currentRate);
        }    

    }   

    update updatedRateList;

}
```

Comment: This is not at all a bulkified trigger. You don't want to put your query inside of a for loop. Get your lists or maps of items first, then run your query all at once, after which your can sort it.

Comment: I am new to this. I am not sure how to specify criteria in my WHERE requirements without naming the variables within the Trigger.new loop. 

Because I am naming the variables based on trigger.new, the SOQL query (which requires these variables) also had to be in the Trigger.new loop. 

Is there a way around this?

Comment: yes, you declare a set or list of the type variable it is, (Id, date, string, etc) and add each one from trigger.new to the set or list. Sets are preferred so you don't get duplicates or list exceptions caused by duplicates. Then in your query, just equate the Set or List to your WHERE criteria fields.

Comment: Can you explain your requirement in simple words? I can then modify your trigger accordingly.